# Skulpt does not support turtle.colormode function?

Tags: python, skulpt

I'm new to [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org) and found that it doesn't fully support the turtle module. Is this the case? E.g., when I try to call the turtle.colormode function (code is below), it generates an error that colormode is not an attribute of the module, see details below.

**Code** (same as the example on Skulp's website except for line 3):

```
import turtle

turtle.colormode(255)  # new line of code causing error

t = turtle.Turtle()

for c in ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']:
    t.color(c)
    t.forward(75)
    t.left(90)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>.py", line 3, in <module>
    turtle.colormode(255)
AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'colormode'
```

Comment: If Skulpt doesn't implement the full turtle module, is there somewhere I can find how much it does implement? It's strange that it wouldn't implement the colormode() function since colors can be specified in JS as 3 integers in the range 0..255, which is the mode that line 3 is requesting.